# deployment of queue.xml to new non-default version does not create queues

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use task queues in GAE Java 8, but somehow it does not seem to deploy correctly via the queue.xml file. I can also not see the task queues in the Cloud Tasks console (which is where I get redirected from the app engine console).
I get an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified queue is unknown : xxxxx` when running the app.
The app runs fine locally. I can see the task queues appearing locally in the admin page.

Does this mean that I cannot deploy task queues via queue.xml anymore?

Comment: How are you attempting to deploy exactly?

Comment: I was using mvn appengine:deploy. But your answer below solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that the queue configuration is not a per-version config (or even a per-service one!), it is a global, per-application config. Or per-project if you want - considering that there can only be one GAE application per GCP project.

This single queue configuration is shared by all versions of all services of your application, so:

- if/when services/versions need different queue configs all of them need to be merged into a single file for deployment.
- pay attention at deployment not to overwrite/negatively impact existing services/versions

While in some cases the `queue.xml` file *might* be deployed automatically when you deploy your application code **it is not always** the case. The official recommended deployment method is using the deployment command dedicated for the queue configuration, which can be performed independently from deploying application/service code. From [Deploying the queue configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/queueref#deploying_the_queue_configuration_file):

> To deploy the queue configuration file without otherwise altering the
>   currently serving version, use the command:
>
> ```
> appcfg.sh update_queues <application directory>
> ```
>
> replacing `<application directory>` with the path to your application
>   main directory.

Pay extra attention if you have:

- other non-java standard environment services in your app - they use the [queue.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/queueref-yaml) queue configuration file, managing the same content in 2 different files/formats can be tricky
- other services managing queue via using Cloud Tasks. See [Using Queue Management versus queue.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/queue-yaml).

Comment: It might be good to also state that ```gcloud app deploy queue.yaml``` works without having to install the sdk, but does require to convert the file to yaml (xml does not seem to work).

Comment: the `gcloud` command (from the cloud SDK) isn't mentioned as an option to deploy the xml file (appcfg.sh is from the java GAE SDK).